# Convert callback to Promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, promise

I want to convert the below callEndPointWrapper to return a Promise instead of callback.
I have tested with the below code, but awaiting on Promise for callEndpointWrapper() the request is timing out.
Am I missing any thing below?
(While debugging I see the request times out on below line of code while awaiting for Promise:
`return (function callEndpoint(callback): any {`

CallBack:

```
    function callEndPointWrapper(): any {
        return function callEndpoint(callback) {
            try {
                // gRPC call
                client[methodName](req, options, callback);
            }
            catch (err) {
                callback(err);
            }
        };
    }
const result = yield callEndpointWrapper();
// I get the correct result from callback above (both on success or error)
```

Promise:

```
function callEndPointWrapper(): Promise<any> {
  return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
    return (function callEndpoint(callback): any {
      try {
        // gRPC call
        resolve(client[methodName](req, options, callback));
      } catch (err) {
        reject(callback(err));
      }
    });
  });
const result = await callEndpointWrapper();
// Above request times out.
```

Comment: It's a bit confusing on what this code does. The callback based code returns a function that accepts a callback but that returned function is actually the one that does some async work...do you mean you need something like `await callEndpointWrapper()()`...(notice 2 invocations)? What's the point of having the wrapper function at all if you're not passing any config options to be available in the closure of the `callEndpoint` function?

Comment: @nem035 Thank you for your reply, it should be a single invocation i.e. `await callEndPointWrapper()` and the request (req) and options are being set earlier as global variables before calling the `callEndpointWrapper`.

Comment: Are you using [`co`](https://github.com/tj/co)?

Comment: Yes with the wrapper I was using `co` earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The desired result of `callEndPointWrapper` seems to be a function (`callEndPoint`) that does some asynchronous work which you can further invoke to do something.

In your callback approach you are producing this `callEndPoint` function.

----> `callEndPointWrapper` returns `callEndPoint` which does async work.

In your promise based approach on the other hand, you are attempting to produce the result of `callEndPoint` rather than return `callEndPoint` itself. In fact, `callEndPoint` is never invoked within the `Promise` constructor.

----> `callEndPointWrapper` returns a promise which never resolves and internally creates the `callEndPoint` function that does nothing because it's never invoked.

It's important to note that a single call to `callEndPointWrapper` is not async. The actual async part (assuming `client` methods are async) happens in `callEndpoint` so an async invocation for your callback-based approach would be something like:

```
callEndPointWrapper()(
  function callback(responseFromEndpoint) {
    // ...
  }
)

// or something like
let caller = callEndPointWrapper();
caller(function callback(responseFromEndpoint) {
    // ...
});
```

From this follows that the promise based approach would require two invocations as well:

```
await callEndPointWrapper()(); // call a wrapper which returns a function which returns a promise
```

A functionally equivalent (in terms of the produced result) promise-based code for your callback code is the following:

```
function callEndPointWrapper(): any {
    return function callEndpoint() {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try {
          client[methodName](req, options, (err, result) => {
            if (err) return reject(err);
            resolve(result);
          });
        } catch (err) {
          // Note: this rejection will only happen on any sync errors
          // with the above code, such as trying to invoke a non-existing
          // method on the client. This type of error is a programmer error
          // rather than an operational error in the system so you should
          // consider if such errors should even by caught by your code.
          reject(err);
        }
      });
   };
}
```

However, this leads to the question of what's the point of having the wrapper function at all if you're not passing any config options to be available in the closure of the `callEndpoint` function?

Based on your example usage, all you need is the `callEndpoint` method.

---

It comes to mind that you might be using something like [`co`](https://github.com/tj/co) which allows you to `yield` functions (thunks) and invokes them internally with a callback.

So when you do

```
yield callEndpointWrapper()
```

you are actually calling

```
yield function callEndpoint(callback) {
  // ...
}
```

And then `co` does some magic under the hood for you.

This is a pattern that is [deprecated by `co`](https://github.com/tj/co#thunks) and is overall ill-advised to use. Not to mention that it's very confusing (and ugly IMHO) behavior that requires knowledge of the particular library.

To use promises with `co`, you don't need the wrapper function. Just `yield` or `await` the result of calling `callEndPoint` (the same one from my promise example above), which will be a promise.

```
yield callEndPoint()
// or
await callEndPoint()
```